# deploy go application via jenkins

Tags: go, jenkins

I just created two EC2 instances, one with Jenkins and one for the go application.

I managed to create a node and a job that works together, and after starting the job for building the go application, I get the go files inside the workspace folder.

and I don't understand what I need to do from now. I can't run `go run server.go` because it's doesn't in the go src folder so I am getting an error that the namespace doesn't exist.

This is the error i get:

```
server.go:7:2: cannot find package "freelancers/daos" in any of:
    /usr/lib/golang/src/freelancers/daos (from $GOROOT)
    /home/ec2-user/projects/src/freelancers/daos (from $GOPATH)
```

Comment: Can you paste the error you get? That would make it easier for us to help debug.

Comment: @robbrit i edited with the error, freelancers is the namespace of course

Comment: Using Jenkins to do this end-to-end is kind of a strange workflow. You might consider using Jenkins to manage your AWS instances (so AWS does the standing up), or using Jenkins to manage your Heroku app (so Heroku does the standing up) or etc. (Though I should say that this is certainly possible!)

Comment: Is your go-app running at least in localhost without Jenkins ? Also where are you running this : go run server.go : Ec2 with Jenkins or EC2 with go  ?

Comment: @JRichardsz, if course its runnig in localhost. And in the ec2 with go, not the one with jenkins. The problem is the path. If I could change jenkins to create the File in another dir and not in workspace, its should solve the problem

Comment: Where does `freelancers/daos` come from? Is it fetched already? If it is, where is it?

Comment: everything works on my computer and Heroku, freelancers/daos is a package inside my app. there is no problem with the application itself. just with Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Set you environment correctly 
https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SettingGOPATH

Make sure package "freelancers/daos" is downloaded correctly to right path.

Run and check your go env settings